# Upvalues for Missing do not work with Dataset

Tags: dataset, upvalues, missing

Consider the following Dataset:

```
d = Dataset[<| 1 -> Missing[], 2 -> 1.0, 3 -> 4.0 |>]
```

And the following Upvalue for Missing:

```
Unprotect[Missing];
Missing /:
f_Symbol[___, m_Missing,  ___] /; MemberQ[Attributes[f], NumericFunction ] := m;
Protect[Missing];
```

Now do the following:

```
d[All,  1 + # &]
```

It returns `<|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2., 3 -> 5.|>` rather than the expected `<|1 -> Missing[], 2 -> 2., 3 -> 5.|>`.

Why doesn't the upvalue for `Missing[]` work?

Comment: I think you have probably discovered a bug in the implementation of `Dataset`. As it stands, your question is probably a bit long and it contains details irrelevant to the issue (i.e. the overloading of `Missing`). I'd suggest that you excise the "UPDATE" part of your question and repost it as a new one, since it has probably gone entirely unnoticed. For what it's worth, I am on MMA 10.4.0 / Win7-64, and I can reproduce the `Dataset` erroneous behavior you mentioned in the update. Would you also please report this to Wolfram Support so it can be identified as a bug?

Comment: Thanks MarcoB. I agree there are two different issues. One, why doesn't overloading of Missing works. And two, why  evaluating multiple times gives two different answers.

Comment: @MarcoB, I changed this question. And created a new one here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114921/evaluating-same-expression-twice-gives-two-distinct-answers-problem-with-datase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, any queries using `Dataset` or `Query` perform special processing of `Missing` values.  The installed up-value will have no effect while that special processing is in place.  We can use `MissingBehavior -> None` to disable the special treatment and to allow our up-value to take effect:

```
d[All, 1 + # &, MissingBehavior -> None]

(* <|1 -> Missing[], 2 -> 2., 3 -> 5.|> *)
```

In general, I would discourage adding an up-value to a protected system symbol like `Missing`.  The present observed difficulty is an example of why -- many components make assumptions about the exact behaviour of built-in symbols.  At the very least, I would recommend using `Block` (or `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``) to keep the redefinition somewhat localized.

Incidentally, the dataset machinery that performs the special missing processing happens to ignore this advice.  It temporarily redefines the behaviour of `Missing` (using `Block`).  That is why `Missing` appears to behave erratically in this context.

Comment: Thanks @WReach. Is this missingbehavior setting documented?

Comment: I just saw it is documented

Comment: starting from a fresh kernel and setting MissingBehavior to automatic does not make the  evaluation of the first element of the expression d[All,  1 + # &] be Missing[]. It is still 1.

Comment: The `Automatic` setting is the default.  It must be set to `None`.

Comment: Thanks @WReach. But in this case, even with a fresh kernel and the Automatic setting, the evalution returns '1' in my computer,  rather than 'Missing' (as expected according to the documentation).

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure what you are getting at.  Under the _Details_ section in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MissingBehavior.html) it is stated that the `Automatic` option changes additive operators so that _Missing elements are dropped or ignored_.  In our case we have the additive expression `1 + Missing[]`.  Therefore, the missing element is dropped yielding a value of `1`.  To inhibit this behaviour (and, incidentally, enable our up-value) we must use the `None` option.

Comment: Thanks That's definitely not clear from the documentation. Why is Plus supposed to be equivalent to the behavior of Total, Mean, etc (which operate in lists) rather than with Times, Power, etc.?