# Evaluating same expression twice gives two distinct answers. Problem with Dataset?

Tags: bugs, dataset, missing

**Bug present in 10.4.1 and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

Consider the following Dataset:

```
d = Dataset[<|1 -> Missing[], 2 -> 2.0|>]
```

Now evaluate

```
d[All, 1 + # &]
```

It gives: `<|1 -> 1, 2 -> 3.|>`.

Evaluate it one more time. It returns:

```
 <|1 -> 1 + Missing[], 2 -> 3.|>
```

Is this a bug?

See also the potentially related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114562/upvalues-for-missing-do-not-work-with-dataset).

Comment: I don't have any problems in version 10.3 on OS X 10.11.4.

Comment: Thanks @xslittlegrass. I am using 10.4.1 on OSX. In  the comments of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114562/upvalues-for-missing-do-not-work-with-dataset, another user also found the problem in 10.4.0 on windows.

Comment: Yes, I had confirmed the problem described on MMA 10.4.0 , Win7-64. @ecoxlinux Have you had a chance to report this to Wolfram support?

Comment: @MarcoB I did submit the report

Comment: If anyone can verify whether the defect exists in v10.4.0 and/or v11.0.0, please update the bug header appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in the implementation of the `MissingBehavior` option of `Dataset`.  The bug was present in version 10.4.1 and fixed by the time of version 11.0.1.

**Analysis (current as of version 11.0.1)**

By default, a dataset query defaults to the option `MissingBehavior -> Automatic`.  This applies special behaviour that is tolerant of the presence of `Missing[]` in data.  In the case at hand, the expression `1 + Missing[]` is interpreted as simply `Plus[1]` (i.e. the `Missing[]` is interpreted as an empty sequence).

The problem arises in the implementation of this special missing behaviour.  It is done by temporarily installing extra definitions upon the symbol `Missing`.  These definitions are installed by the internal function `` Dataset`BlockMissingBehavior ``.

In version 10.4 this function would only install the extra definitions if a certain global symbol lacked an undocumented property.  But there was a bug because, as the definitions were applied, the undocumented property was set upon the symbol as a side-effect.  The presence of the property in the second and subsequent evaluations would prevent the extra `Missing` definitions from being applied and the query would behave as if the option `MissingBehavior -> None` had been specified.

In version 11, the special definitions are now installed unconditionally so the defect no longer appears.  Versions prior to 10.4 also installed the definitions unconditionally.